# Adding test class for my code

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm struggling with the following problem for two days. I want to create a test class for apex class. here is some of the code:

```
public class Matched_Refunded_SF_Tickets_Cnt
{
    public List<MatchingTicketsLibrary.MatchedTicketWrapper> unmatchedTickets { get { return Filter.unmatchedTickets; } }

    public String selectedTicket { get; set; }

    public Filter filter { get{ if (filter==null) filter = new Filter(); return filter; } set; }

    @TestVisible class Filter
    {
        public List<MatchingTicketsLibrary.MatchedTicketWrapper> unmatchedTickets { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how to give a value to unmatchedTickets variable in Test class and then this value is used in the other member functions of the class...?

Answer (score 0):

The `unmatchedTickets` data originates in the filter so you can set it there to an empty list and/or to a list that has values:

```
// Add empty list
Matched_Refunded_SF_Tickets_Cnt m = new Matched_Refunded_SF_Tickets_Cnt();
m.filter.unmatchedTickets = new List<MatchingTicketsLibrary.MatchedTicketWrapper>();

// Add values to the list using whatever constuctors are available
m.filter.unmatchedTickets.add(new MatchingTicketsLibrary.MatchedTicketWrapper(...));
m.filter.unmatchedTickets.add(new MatchingTicketsLibrary.MatchedTicketWrapper(...));
```